# MKL dgemv - Invalid memory access for dynamically allocated arrays

Tags: c++, blas, intel-mkl, intel-inspector

I do a blas matrix/vector product with this simple code:

```
#include "mkl.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
const int M = 2;
const int N = 3;
double *x = new double[N];
double *A = new double[M*N];
double *b = new double[M];
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++){
    b[i] = 0.0; //Not necessary but anyway...
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){
        A[j * M + i] = i + j * 2;
    }
}
for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    x[j] = j*j;
const int incr = 1;
const double alpha = 1.0;
const double beta = 0.0;
const char no = 'N';
dgemv(&no, &M, &N, &alpha, A, &M, x, &incr, &beta, b, &incr );
printf("b = [%e %e]'\n",b[0],b[1]);

delete[] x;
delete[] A;
delete[] b;

}
```

While the displayed result is as expected ([18, 23]), Intel Inspector finds one *invalid memory access* and 2 *invalid partial memory access* when calling dgemv. The *invalid memory access* and one *invalid partial memory access* are related to memory allocated corresponding to the vector b. The second *invalid partial memory access* is related with the memory allocated for A. I do not get any error if I use a static array.

It also happens with other MKL functions, such as dgesv or when I try to use cblas_dgemv. I use Intel Inspector XE 2016 and intel C++ Compiler 16.0  with MKL sequential.

Is my dgemv call wrong, or is that a false positive. Anyone experienced that?

Thanks

EDIT:

As suggested by Josh Milthorpe: the error appears only on small-size arrays, probably because MKL is trying to access memory in large chunks for efficiency.

I did several tests, and M needs to be at least 20 in order to not get an error. N can be any positive number. I suppose that this is not a bug, and MKL is just accessing memory outside of the allocated space for the matrix, but does not alter or really use it.

Comment: If all your arrays have a size fixed at the time of compilation, why don't you use actual arrays instead of allocating dynamically?

Comment: This is just a minimal  example to reproduce the problem. On this example blas is a bit overkill and I could also do the product by hand ;-). Variable size arrays are needed in my larger code.

Comment: Your `dgemv` call looks fine to me.  I suspect MKL is trying to access memory in large chunks for efficiency, which is causing some bug for small matrix/vector sizes.  Does Inspector report these accesses for larger input sizes?

Comment: Excellent guess: I have no error detected with larger arrays (e.g. M=100, N=200). Now a follow-up question: do you think MKL actually does something wrong for small matrices (like altering memory outside of the arrays), or should I just ignore the reported errors? This sizes of the matrices are usually large in my code, but sometimes they are small.

Comment: I couldn't say; if the invalid access is only a read, it may not cause any problems, whereas if it's a write, it could cause trouble later on.  You might want to report it to Intel.

Comment: I reported this on the intel forum. Not sure that I understand correctly, but it looks like it is safe to use dgemv for any matrix: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library/topic/701545